# Is there a method to add shortcode to a custom widget in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget

I am looking for a simple way to add shortcode to a custom widget(Not in custom template)  which i have created using my function file in wordpress,so this shortcode can be used to show my custom stuffs..?Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress widgets aren’t enabled to manage shortcodes.So there is a simple trick which can 
be used here.
Open your function file and write the following code

```
add_filter(‘widget_text’, ‘do_shortcode’);
```

More can be found [here](http://wpworld.in/add-shortcode-widget/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the shortcode in widget script, you need to add a function like:

```
echo do_shortcode('[your_shortcode]');
```